# Check whether xpath value is contained in a list

Tags: xslt

I have to set a variable value in XSLT based on whether the value in an xpath is one among a list of values. Is there any way other than doing

```
<xsl:variable name="isBuyable">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$someVar='A'">
            <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$someVar='B'">
            <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$someVar='C'">
            <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

or like

```
<xsl:variable name="isBuyable">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$someVar='A' or $someVar='B' or $someVar='C'">
            <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

`someVar` holds the value in an xpath.

Is it possible to do something like `<xsl:when test="contains($listVar, $someVar)>"` where `listVar` is a variable holding the list of required values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can have sequences of atomic values, so you can do

```
<xsl:variable name="isBuyable" select="$someVar = ('A', 'B', 'C')" />
```

In 1.0 you only have node sets, not atomic sequences, so it's a bit more fiddly. If your processor supports a `node-set` extension function (the msxsl one for Microsoft processors, exslt for most others) then you can do

```
<xsl:variable name="buyableValuesRTF">
  <val>A</val>
  <val>B</val>
  <!-- etc -->
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="buyableValues" select="exslt:node-set($buyableValuesRTF)/val"/>
```

to create a node set with the valid values, which you can then compare against:

```
<xsl:variable name="isBuyable" select="$someVar = $buyableValues"/>
```

In both versions this works because an `=` comparison where one argument (or both) is a sequence succeeds if *any* of the elements on the left matches *any* of the ones on the right.

To do it in 1.0 without an extension function you'll have to fake the sequence using substring matching - define the list of allowed values as a string delimited by some character that is not in any of the values

```
<xsl:variable name="buyableValues" select="'|A|B|C|'"/>
```

and use the `contains` function to check for a substring:

```
<xsl:variable name="isBuyable" select="contains($buyableValues,
    concat('|', $someVar, '|'))"/>
```

Comment: I'm using 1.0 and was thinking of doing it using subsring if the list way is not there.